# Creating iGraph object by matching ID numbers

Tags: r, matrix, networking, igraph, edges

I am seeking a solution to an issue relating to the creation of an `igraph` object for my masters thesis. I need to conduct a network analysis for database which matches participant by project ID - there are about 1500 total rows consisting of about 600 or so different participants, and about 300 or so projects. Multiple participants are involved in multiple different projects. A sample of the code is below

```
   Participant_ID Project_Number
1               1         101314
2               2         101314
3               3         101314
4               1         101314
5               5         101346
6               6         101346
7               7         101346
8               8         101531
9               9         101531
10              3         101531
11             11         101533
12              8         101533
13              3         101533
14             14         101533
15              9         101612
```

How can I match these in a way that creates a network? How could I code these into an edge list - whether it be via a matrix or otherwise, as there are so many observations and differing numbers of participants on each project. I'm finding it hard to find much online that shows how I can create an edge list by ID numbers, and I need to overcome what I imagine is a fairly ordinary few lines of code.

Comment: **** I notice that there is a duplicate in the same - I've anonymised the participant id's as they are actually names of people, but there are no duplicates in the actual dataset, just to clear up

Answer (score 0):

Like this? `Project_Number` must be converted into a factor to prevent the creation of a graph with 100k+ nodes:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

graph <-
  tribble(
    ~Participant_ID, ~Project_Number,
    1, 101314,
    2, 101314,
    3, 101314,
    1, 101314
  ) %>%
  mutate(Project_Number = Project_Number %>% factor()) %>%
  tbl_graph(edges = .)
graph
#> # A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 4 edges
#> #
#> # A directed acyclic multigraph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 4 × 1 (active)
#>   name  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 1     
#> 2 101314
#> 3 2     
#> 4 3     
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 4 × 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     3     2
#> 3     4     2
#> # … with 1 more row

graph %>% as.igraph() %>% plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bipartite graph could help

```
graph_from_data_frame(df) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% df$Participant_ID) %>%
  plot(layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image]

---

If you want a matrix output, you can try

```
> table(df)
              Project_Number
Participant_ID 101314 101346 101531 101533 101612
            1       2      0      0      0      0
            2       1      0      0      0      0
            3       1      0      1      1      0
            5       0      1      0      0      0
            6       0      1      0      0      0
            7       0      1      0      0      0
            8       0      0      1      1      0
            9       0      0      1      0      1
            11      0      0      0      1      0
            14      0      0      0      1      0
```